# ASP.NET multiple columns DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I simply create a multi-columns DropDownList in ASP.NET ?

**I am not looking for a simple concatenation like :**

```
"Col1 :" + Value1 + " --- Col2 :" + Value2;
```

I am looking for something more complex than just a concatenation, because **I want to have the possibility to search on X columns with a filter**.

I know there's a lot of similar answer out there, but these questions are old or no longer used(link broken, old tuto, etc.).

So I am looking for something **up-to-date**.

I am open to use a plugin (There is no need to reinvent the wheel). I know there's a lot of plugin out there, but seriously, as an indie dev, I don't have 1000$ to buy devexpress or telerik.

I am working with ASP.NET webform - c#.

Comment: Create your own. Upon click on dropdown selection - display your own GridView, positioned at correct coordinates

Comment: I like the idea, it look simple ! I will take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I have used following jquery It worls like charm..

[MEGA DROPDOWN](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/)

Comment: Problem one: Link only answers are discouraged. Problem 2: This is a dropdown menu not a DropDownList i.e. more like a `<select>` list in HTML.